# loop through returned results node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops

I am getting results returned from my request made to my server. It is returning multiple lines, in which each line is a new entry into the array.

So right now I am logging it as:

```
completion.data.choices[0].text
```

and it is obviously only returning the first one. But i want it to return all of them.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to log all the choices, you can use a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop

```
completion.data.choices.forEach(choice => {
  console.log(choice.text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 completion.data.choices.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item.text)
    }
```